# "can't dump File" during "Rails.cache.fetch" and "Rails.cache.write"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord

I been working on porting my application on "Rails 3.0.7" ,ever since I started to employ caching for my application either (file cache,memcache or any other) . I always happen to get the above error "can't dump File" .

I Google a bit and found that it has something to do with Marshal dump as ruby interpreter does allow Marshal dump of object that have Procs or lambdas in them so I looked upon my code but I could not find any Proc and lambda in my whole applications

Now to discover the problem I drill down the ActiveRecord 3.0.7 code and here are few interesting finding that I came up with

**1 .** "includes" in Rails 3 + internally call the define **name scope**  OK this I give the answer that there is Proc and Lambada associated with the object so the error **but** this doesn't explain why **the same code work sometime and report with errors(above errors)** other times I mean If the error is for the Marshalling and object that hold a Proc or a Lambada then code should definitely not work and should always report errors no matter how many times the same code is ran **but that not the case over here** the code return **errors** sometimes and **work well** other times

Code

> Rails.cache.fetch("accessible_websites_1")
>   { Website.includes(:account) }

**2 .** If the **".includes"** in Rails 3.0 + has problem then what up with **other 'include'** syntax  does it too report error (above error)
so I ran the code with **older syntax** of **include**

Here is it

> Rails.cache.fetch("accessible_websites_1")
>   {     Website.all(:include =>
>   :account) }

well surprisingly it ran but it **never preloaded the account  related** for all the website **( which is where weird)** but at least It never gave and error 
so did a forensic on Active Record 3.0 + once again to discover how the older version of **include**(Rails 2.3 +) work surprise to know that the older version of **include** syntax **internally call** the **.includes method** of ActiveRecord 3.0 +

whoo How is that possible 
 two different syntax both call the same internal method one report with error **sometimes ( not every time but preload the associated object**) and other **does not** report with error **but neither preload the associated object** as said earlier.

OK , Hearing all this if anyone can help me out then I would be utmost grateful

By the way

Here what I'm trying to achieve

> Rails.cache.fetch("accessible_websites_1")
>   { Website.includes(:account) }

the equivalent code of above in Rails 2.3.5 and Rails 3 + (but **does not preload** the associated account object of all websites)
i.e

> Rails.cache.fetch("accessible_websites_1")
>   { Website.find(:all,:include =>
>   :account) }

Work perfectly fine without any issue

I using

> Ruby = "ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10
>   patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]"   Rails
>   = " Rails 3.0.7"

The same Problem even persisted on **Rails 3.1.0**

am I missing something

I can also provide the model structure if required

Comment: No I'm not marshalling  an instance of File

Comment: Yes I'm aware of Rails Cache using Marshal internally and no I'm not storing and instance of File any how in my code.Plus the error is not persistent as mention in my  question above. I can also share the code if your interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
Website.includes(:account)
```

does not load the data, it just provides you with a proxy object that will load the objects on demand when you do something like calling `#each` or `#to_s`, if you force the fetching by adding a `#to_a`at the end it should work, e.g. try

```
Marshal.dump(Website.includes(:account))
Marshal.dump(Website.includes(:account).to_a)
```

`#all(x=>y)` does not do the same thing as `#x(y)`, that is why you can do `X.includes.joins.where` but not `X.all.where`.

Not sure where the reference to a `File` comes from though.

Comment: Are You speaking in regards to Rails 3 (which I think is true)cuz this it is so untrue  in Rails 2.3+ as I tested above before posting the question .Also the error is replicating in Rails 3+ and not in Rails 2.3+ cuz Ruby Marshal doesn't except "Proc" in them Which is weird digging through source code found Rails new includes internally call the old syntax of 2.3+  also the error was not persistent as describe above.

Comment: yes, I am talking about rails 3, because the question appears to be about porting to rails3. I advice you share the code, it may help us help you.